# Question 10 from N.L Carothers' "Real Analysis", Chapter 11.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(x_{i})$ be a sequence of numbers in $(0,1)$ such that the $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^k$ exists for every k=0,1,2,.... Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{i})$ exists for every $f \in C[0,1]$.

I believe I need to that the sequence $\{g_{n}\}_{n\geq 1} = \big\{(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{i})\big\}_{n\geq 1}$ is Cauchy, but I am not too sure how to do this. I do know that to show the sequence is Cauchy, one must have that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists$ N s.t $|g_{m}-g_{n}| \leq \epsilon$ $\forall$ m,n $\geq$ N.

Comment: Use Stone–Weierstrass.

Comment: Or just Weierstrass: Any continuous function on $[0,1]$ is uniformly approximated by polynomials...